# Two workspaces, tfe_output

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to use output values from a 2nd workspace in my current one.
For example:

```
data "tfe_outputs" "EKS" {
        organization = "EKS_Deploy"
        workspace = "EKS_Deploy"
}
```

Then I need EKS cluster ID in one of my modules from that 2nd workspace (I already set up outputs):

**2nd workspace**

```
output "eks_cluster_id" {
  description = "EKS Cluster ID"
  value       = module.eks-ssp.eks_cluster_id
}
```

**1st workspace**

```
eks_cluster_id = data.tfe_outputs.EKS.eks_cluster_id
```

But, running a `terraform apply` in the second workspace throws this:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute
on main.tf line 22, in data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster":
  name = data.tfe_outputs.EKS.eks_cluster_id
This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "eks_cluster_id".
```

This is strange to me, since I can see the correct output value in my 2nd workspace, ie. it shows a proper output. So I'm guessing I'm calling it wrong somehow. What could it be?

Comment: As per example [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tfe/latest/docs/data-sources/outputs) aren't you missing `.values` (should be `data.tfe_outputs.EKS.values.eks_cluster_id`)?

Comment: That indeed was the issue, thank you.